# How do I place an UpdateLock on a row with an index

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, locking

Let's assume I have a table like this on a SQL Server 2014:

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OwnerId int NOT NULL,
    Balance bigint NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT PK_Account PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id ASC),
CONSTRAINT UQ_OwnerId UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED (OwnerId)
)
```

Let's assume that there is a row with `Id=1`, `OwnerId=1` and `Balance=100`.

I need to select the Id for a specific Account (only the *Id*) but at the same time would like to lock the row against updates.

In the first session I execute the following statement (in a transaction):

```
SELECT Id FROM Accounts WITH (UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK) WHERE OwnerId = 1;
```

In the second session I execute the following statement (in another transaction):

```
UPDATE Accounts SET Balance = 500 WHERE Id = 1;
```

Both statements complete without being blocked, because the first statement locks on the unique index. What can I do to force the second statement to wait?

Solutions I've already come up with, but don't like:

1. Select the whole row (`SELECT *`) instead of only the id on the first query → This results in too much overhead in my application.
2. Add an `INDEX=PK_Account` hint to the first query to force locking on the PK → I lose performance because this results in a clustered index scan.

Is there any other way to retrieve only the *Id* (while using the *UQ_OwnerId*) and prevent any update to the row?

Comment: What transaction isolation level are you using?

Comment: Currently READ COMMITED (without Snapshot), but I think it should not matter much?

Comment: I bet you're coming from Oracle :-) Not because it's inherently bad, but it's how you would typically do things in Oracle. Why do you need to lock the row on reading? This is a sign that you're probably performing too many operations in your transaction, which won't help concurrency.

Comment: Actually no I am a MS guy :-).
I need to execute a few checks in the application but cannot rollback and retry on a conflict.

Comment: and Balance is not null might fool it.   those two wheres are not the same

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly Paparazi, but yes, the where clauses are not the same. That is part of the problem.

Comment: Try updlock, holdlock. The rowlock hint won't always be enforced.

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik: That does not work. The problem is not that the lock is not enforced, but that the lock targets the index instead of the table.

Comment: @mjr Alright, so, perf would probably tank in a similar way with serializable and repeatable read hints. You could try a combination of readcommittedlock and readpast hints, with readpast there to attempt to give you some semblance of concurrency, but you'd have to do a lot of testing to make sure you don't read anything funky, or hit any race conditions. I'm usually wary of adding hints like this to existing applications. The overall design may not be set up to handle them.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but in your example you use OwnerID in one statements and Id in another. It's not understood that the row with ID = 1 is the same row as OwnerID = 1. Thus given your scenario I don't see a reason why it should be blocked as they may not even be the same row.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Yeah, sorry about that. I did not mention that those are the same row. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: Two seeks, and lock on PK , `select id from Accounts WITH (UPDLOCK)
where id = (select a.id from Accounts a where a.OwnerId=1 )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two seeks, and lock on PK,

```
select id 
from Accounts WITH (UPDLOCK) 
where id = (select a.id from Accounts a where a.OwnerId=1)
```